# The use of the word “what”

Tags: parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

Which of the two following sentences is or are correct?

1. Excessive logging of forests in the past century has resulted **in what becomes known** as deforestation.
2. Excessive logging of forests in the past century has resulted **in what known** as deforestation.

What is the role of *what* in these sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Excessive logging of forests in the past century has resulted in [***what*** becomes known as deforestation].
> 2. Excessive logging of forests in the past century has resulted in ***what*** known as deforestation.
>
> What is the role of WHAT in these sentences?

Your #2 version is ungrammatical.

Your #1 version is fine. The word "what" is the relative word that heads a **fused-relative construction.** What is happening in your sentence is that the word "what" is doing two functions at once: it is the relative word beginning a relative clause (the stuff inside the brackets), and it is the antecedent for the relative word. That is, your #1 version is similar to:

- Excessive logging of forests in the past century has resulted in [***something which*** becomes known as deforestation].

In the above example, the antecedent is the word "something", and the word "which" is the relative word that begins the relative clause. But in your version #1, the word "what" has to fulfill both of those functions: it's equivalent to the phrase "something which" in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Excessive logging of forests in the past century has resulted in what's known as deforestation.

Comment: Please tell me why this sentence has 2 verbs 'has resulted in' and 'is known' but it is still grammatically correct? Since as far as I know WHAT is not a relative pronoun. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you think that *"what"* is not a relative pronoun? You should look in a [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/what?q=what).